# Android - inapp billing package not shown in my Android SDK manager

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am following these instructions:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download

and they say to open the Android SDK manager and install the extras --> InApp Billing package.  But I don't have that option.

Under exras I just have Android Support package which it says I have downloaded, and something from Intel.

But when I go to my C:\program files\android\android-sdk\ there is a bunch of things there, but nothing resembling the inapp billing package.

Any ideas how I can get that package and what might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: genadinik: i am having this same problem canu help me how have u solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\program files\android\android-sdk\extras\google\market_billing
```

Comment: I don't have that extras\google directory.  I only have extras\android and in it is some weird stuff. :)

Comment: Did you install the blling package? Check the location of your sdk.. It should be there if it was installed...

Comment: I don't even have the option of the billing package when I try to install it from the sdk manager.  That is the problem I think